# telerik radscheduler in iPhone

Tags: telerik

when i click on the telerik radscheduler the whole screen is selected (thou i clicked on the appointment) and then i have to select on the particular event to handle some navigation... is there any way to avoid such experience for the user like screen getting selected as whole ???

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this an IPhone feature (to display select "shadow" for the focused element)? Disclaimer: I am not an expert and may be completely off course, and the better option is to direct your question to telerik.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is an iOS feature similar to focus outline. To remove it on the whole page, use this CSS:

```
* { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; }
```